# Desire2Learn Revoking User Keys

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am unable to revoke application access by a user via either a password reset or by explicitly clearing app keys in user management. The latter method gives a reply indicating that access has been revoked, but when the user hits the tool, they are not re-prompted to approve access to their information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of possibilities here:

- It's possible that there is latency between the declared revocation of keys and the cleanup task that goes through the database and actually cleans them up; I believe that at one point, such a latency existed, was identified, and fixed through service packs and subsequent releases. Accordingly, you may address this issue by ensuring that your back-end service is up-to-date with its available service packs.
- It's possible that what's being revoked is the keys, and the necessity to authenticate to rebuild keys, but *not* the confirmation step that would appear to the user asking for access permission (assuming the user once authenticated, and checked the "don't prompt me to ask for permission again") dialog.

Can you confirm if the request for user tokens by the client application actually does get back tokens? Or is it just that the authentication step happens with no notice of client confirmation to access?

Note that the re-authentication might appear to happen *silently*; if the client application's request for user tokens happens through a user's browser context where the back-end service can determine that the user is already logged in to the LMS, then the request for tokens could succeed automatically:

- The user is assumed to have already authenticated in order to have an active web session, so there's no need to re-gather a username/password (or whatever user auth step the LMS uses) to re-confirm identity.
- The user *may* already have *confirmed access* for the application *and* dismissed the confirmation step with "don't ask me again". If the user has confirmed access with "don't ask me again" this choice will get remembered, *even if the user tokens get expired due to password change or access revocation by an admin*.

If you explicitly log a user out of their LMS session, and then test the client app, this should indicate to you visibly whether the re-authentication step is actually taking place (the user's browser will then get directed to the login process for the back-end service).

Note that, although a user password change or access revocation by an admin can remove the recorded user Id/Key pair associated with an application, it *does not* remove the record of the confirmation form having been dismissed with "don't ask again". Currently our system does not expose a way to reset that confirmation state.

If after considering these points you feel you still have an issue, I would encourage you to [open a support incident](https://helpdesk.desire2learn.com/) through your organization's approved support contact, or your account or partner manager. Desire2Learn takes security related reports quite seriously, and if you've uncovered an issue that hasn't yet been addressed, I would encourage you to report it as a defect.